# Installing subclipse on Eclipse manually

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, subclipse

I have downloaded subclipse from http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=2240

The zip file i downloaded contains the following two folders and 4 files

```
/features
/plugins
artifacts.xml
content.xml
index.html
site.xml
```

Can i just copy the two folders (features and plugins) on to the $ECLIPSE_HOME folder and ignore the files? I have done this before but i don't remember having to copy individual files.  Can the xml and html files be ignored?

I have to install it manually because the server is behind a proxy and i don't know the proxy details.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

The instructions in the previous answer are not correct.  Subclipse provides a zipped archive site.  You install it the same way you do any plugin, from the Eclipse Install/Updates UI.  Instead of entering a URL, you click the button for new local archived site and then browse and select the zip file.

You cannot simply unzip the site into an Eclipse install.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I was not aware that eclipse allowed installation from a local archive. Will try this now. Thanks

Comment: Here is the correct URL to download from: https://dl.bintray.com/subclipse/releases/subclipse/

Answer (score 4):

follows these steps:

1. go to your Eclipse install's dropins directory
2. create a subfolder and expand your zip into that folder
3. Restart Eclipse